# Replacing String from JSON response String in android

Tags: java, android, json, string

**String replacement is not working**

```
String jsonresponseString ="��  ÿ0{"sid":"QtRm47A_2COfPAO-AANH","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}"
```

**i tried this code**

```
String responseString1 = jsonresponseString.replace("�� ÿ0", "");
```

**I want output like this**

```
{"sid":"v3h9kTn3woDQEijKAANS","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
```

Comment: Are you getting this `��\t\u0007ÿ0` thing only when it starts ?

Comment: `String jsonresponseString ="��  ÿ0{"sid":"QtRm47A_2COfPAO-AANH","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}"` This is **not a string**

Comment: But this is what i am getting from JsonResponse

Comment: No, you are not getting a thing like that. Because the quotes must be escaped to be a valid string.

Answer (score 2):

First line

```
String responseString =  �� ÿ0{"sid":"v3h9kTn3woDQEijKAANS","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
```

is not a valid java code. Have you copy-pasted it from an output of some program? It should be something like

```
String responseString =  "{\"sid\":\"v3h9kTn3woDQEijKAANS\", ...}"
```

I would advice you to double check what generates `responseString`.

Comment: ok, find out what are utf8 encoding of the symbols after the first quotation sign and replace them in this way:  **newString = responseString.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "");**, where \uFFFD is an example of on of possbile utf8 code of the chars you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code :

```
String printjson(String str) {
    // \{\s*\".*\}$|^\[\n?\{\s*\".*\}\n?\]$~s
    Pattern rulePattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*\\\".*\\}$|^\\[\\n?\\{\\s*\\\".*\\}\\n?\\]$~s");
    Matcher a = rulePattern.matcher(str);
    if (a.find()) {
        str = a.group();
    }
    return str;
}


System.out.println(printJson("��  ÿ0{"sid":"QtRm47A_2COfPAO-AANH","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}")
```